# Prevent rsyslog messages from repeating in different priority levels

Tags: logs, rsyslog

[Running Linux Mint 19.3]

I'm trying to work with individual **rsyslog** priority levels, separating out the messages like this (`from /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`):

```
*.info                         /var/log/syslog-pri/syslog.info
*.notice                       /var/log/syslog-pri/syslog.notice
*.warn                         /var/log/syslog-pri/syslog.warn
*.err                          /var/log/syslog-pri/syslog.err
*.crit                         /var/log/syslog-pri/syslog.crit
```

This all works great, except there are a few programs that write their messages to multiple priority levels; **ufw** is the biggest offender, but it's not the only one. Is there a setting in **rsyslog** that will stop a message from repeating in lower priority levels?

Comment: I think you mis-understand priority levels; "crit" means "crit or above".  Similarly "err" means "err or above".  Apps typically only log at a single priority.

Comment: That's where I'm having the problem. For example, when I tail **syslog** or run `journalctl`, I only get (1) message from **ufw** about an IP that it blocked. Using my separated log files from above, I get this message in .warn, .info, and .notice. Is that normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple [filters](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html) rsyslog has many extensions to the original BSD version including:

> You may precede every priority with an equals sign (“=’‘) to specify only this single priority and not any of the above.

So try `*.=err` and so on.

Comment: That did the trick - thank you!